# Edit template of Kendo grid Column dynamically

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which is initially rendered as

```
$("#dataGrid").kendoGrid({ 
                    height: 450,
                    sortable: true,
                    columns:[     
                            {field: "Status", title: " ", width:35},
                            {field: "Year", title:" ", width:50},
                            {field: "Name", title:" ", width:50}
                            ],
                    dataSource: surveydataSource
                });
```

My requirement is that on some function call, I want to change the template of "Name" column in kendo grid as :

```
$("#dataGrid").kendoGrid({ 
                    height: 450,
                    sortable: true,
                    columns:[     
                            {field: "Status", title: " ", width:35},
                            {field: "Year", title:" ", width:50},
                            {field: "Name", title:" ", width:50, template: "<strong>#: name # </strong>"}
                            ],
                    dataSource: surveydataSource
                });
```

Is there any simpler way to do so rather than building entire grid again ? Can I just change/reset the template of a column in kendo grid ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Kendo Grid [.setOptions()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions) method to set this up.

```
var grid = $("#dataGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.setOptions({
        columns: [     
            {field: "Status", title: " ", width:35},
            {field: "Year", title:" ", width:50},
            {field: "Name", title:" ", width:50, template: "<strong>#: name # </strong>"}
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Actually this is just a sample, in actual my columns are quite high in number and many of them have templates. So is there any other way out to just pick that particular column only and apply changes to it ?

Comment: No, because `.setOptions()` will override each property (in this case, **columns**) and apply the entire configuration and recreate the grid internally .